# What is the probability of that a randomly taken page contains any typo?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

> While writing a book, which has $500$ pages, $50$ typos were made. What is the probability of that a randomly taken page contains any typo?

At the first glance, I thought it was $$\frac{50}{500} = \frac {1}{10}$$ But now I'm wondering that it's wrong since we don't how those typos are distributed through the book. If all are in a single page then the probability is $1/500$, if all are in two pages, then the answer is $2/500$, etc. , if there is at most one typo in any page then it's $50/500$. I cannot sum up these probabilities, since they do not seem to be disjoint.

I'm new to the Probability Course, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could assume a Poisson Process, say.  Then each page has typos governed by a poisson distribution with mean $\frac 1{10}$.  That gives a lower probability, as you would expect.  About $.9048$  To stress, however, some assumption is needed. Personally, I prefer the Poisson assumption to the "max one typo per page " assumption which the $\frac 1{10}$ result requires.

Comment: When you do not have any further information about the distribution of typos the best you can do is to assume that typos are uniformly distributed over the pages. So $\frac1  {10}$ is the right answer.

Comment: Or you could use a binomial distribution $1-\left(1-\frac{1}{500}\right)^{50}\approx 0.095$

Comment: @lulu: I think you intended $1-e^{-50/500}$ rather than $e^{-50/500}$

Comment: @Henry  Absolutely, thanks.  Thus, I meant to write $1-.9048=.0952$.